# Magento 2, override \lib\ classes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, plugin, preference

Can you override the classes in `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework` and if so how?
I know how to use **plugins/preferences** to override the classes in  `\code` but these methods do no seem to work with the lib classes. Thanks.

Comment: Which magento version are you used? In latest version no Magento\Framework folder available inside lib\internal folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely feasible using preferences.

You can do something like this in a `di.xml` file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Class\You\Want\To\Rewrite" type="Vendor\Module\Your\Class" />
</config>
```

This method is widely used in the Magento 2 original files, for example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/di.xml

Comment: Yes it will, realized I have tried this already but ended up with other issues. Might ask another more specific question. Thank you.

Comment: @Matt feel free to close this question so it will help others and improve Magento StackExchange answer rate ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I'm trying overriding this class Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Db\UpdateRow but it's not working. I've added <preference> tab in di.xml and also added the class in my module but after doing the operation the page goes blank.  Can you please let me know how did you defined the actual class?

Comment: doesn't work for Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager