# Magento 2 Can Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Write be "preference" or "plugin"?

Tags: magento2, overrides, core, file

Tried to use preference to override it, but errors appear when running "`magento setup:static-content:deploy`".

Then I tried to use plugin, but I found that the system did not go to my customized function.

Is `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Write` overridable?

Comment: after override have you recompile.

Comment: Refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112699/magento-2-override-lib-classes

Comment: I know this is old but.....Did you get this working. I'm having terrible trouble overriding Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Drivers\File